# Тестовая и обучающая выборки (scikit-learn)

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Как правильно задать `X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test`, если тестовая и обучающая выборки лежат в разных файлах. Загружаю их в df_test и df_train (pandas).

Comment: обучать на df_train, проверять на df_test, раз они у вас заранее разделены

Comment: @Nofate а как их конкретно связать с этими переменными, без сплита?

Comment: Из df_train выделите столбец Y_train (зависимая переменная), все остальные столбцы будут для вас X_train (независимые переменные). Точно так же с df_test.

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
In [200]: df_train = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,4)), columns=list('abcd'))

In [201]: df_train
Out[201]:
   a  b  c  d
0  8  4  7  8
1  9  4  3  9
2  9  3  7  4
3  2  1  7  3
4  2  9  0  8
5  5  7  7  2
6  2  8  8  4
7  0  8  0  5
8  5  3  9  1
9  5  9  2  2

In [203]: X_train, y_train = df_train.drop('c',1), df_train['c']

In [204]: X_train
Out[204]:
   a  b  d
0  8  4  8
1  9  4  9
2  9  3  4
3  2  1  3
4  2  9  8
5  5  7  2
6  2  8  4
7  0  8  5
8  5  3  1
9  5  9  2

In [205]: y_train
Out[205]:
0    7
1    3
2    7
3    7
4    0
5    7
6    8
7    0
8    9
9    2
Name: c, dtype: int32
```

PS `df_test` можно разбить точно также...